# Calculate expected number of hours to finish large donuts

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

A box contains $3$ large donuts and $7$ small donuts. Each hour, you randomly choose a donut from the box. If it's a small donut, it's eaten; If it's a large donut, it's cut in half, where one half is eaten and the other half is returned into the box as a small donut. After how many hours is it expected for the box to only have small donuts left?

> The only way I can think of approaching this problem is calculating the probability of finishing the small donuts in n minutes and multiplying that by n for all possible n. However, this seems quite tedious. Is there a more efficient approach to tackling a problem like this?

Comment: The fact that the probabilities of the actions depend on the state of the system seems to be a challenging aspect. So the probability of a single step within a sequence of actions depends on the history of actions taken.

Comment: Clarification requested: "...If it's a large donut, it's cut in half, where one half is eaten and the other half is returned into the box as a small donut." Since the large donut is returned as a small donut, is it to be construed that this particular large donut *has been eliminated*?  Alternatively, must the 2nd half of this large donut be eaten before the large donut is to be regarded as *eliminated*?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $E(3,7) = 113/12$, where $E(m,n)$ is the expected hours for the box to only have small donuts left if there are $m$ large donuts and $n$ small donuts initially.

We have formulas
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(1,n) &=1+\frac{n}{2}\\
E(2,n) & = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{2n}{3}\\
E(3,n)& = \frac{25}{6} + \frac{3n}{4}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
The proof is using induction.